# Apache URL rewrite for subdomain pointing to an existing virtual server resource?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, mod-alias

I'm trying to point `subdomain.example.com` to a resource on `subdomain2.example.com/?page_id=1`

It's a wordpress blog. I'm attempting to give a static page its own subdomain. The point is to basically showcase the existing resource without giving away the URL... So far, I've tried...

> `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}
>   subdomain.example.com [NC]`
>
> `RewriteRule ^(.*)$
>   http://subdomain2.example.com/?page_id=1
>   [P]`

but to no avail.

Currently I have the `subdomain.example.com` set up as its own Virtual server with a RedirectPermanent to the resource. Anyone have any insight on how to achieve this? I think i'm getting closer but I'm very new to this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you also add `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: have you enabled mod_proxy? the [P] flag requires it.

Answer (score 1):

Also see http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite

Comment: Thanks for posting this link, I found a few cases there I've been guilty of in the past. There are several recipes on this page which solve the problem more simply. `ProxyPass` would do this, nyet?

Comment: no, if I understand the problem correctly he always wants to redirect to the same static page, ProxyPass would always append anything after the given hostname to the end of the target and for that reason not always point to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be the flags you're using. [See the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html) for the available flags; my guess is that you want `[L]` instead of `[P]`.

I don't think an entire virtual server is needed for this, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteEngine On` is there, just forgot to include it.

Adding [L] still just rewrites the url to `subdomain2.example.com/?page_id=1` instead of what i want to appear in the browser as `subdomain.example.com`

I was thinking about mimicking the virtualserver for `subdomain2.example.com` and then forcing the `subdomain.example.com` to point to one url, and truncating everything after the .com ?

A huge waste of a virtual server, but...how would I go about that ordeal?